# Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL) 'order by' to keep values together, but without specifying order (partial order by)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by

I am using MSSQL 2008 R2 but this is a general SQL question. I want to sort my results just to keep the same values next to each other, without specifying an exact sort order.

For example

```
create table t (a int not null, b int not null)

insert into t values (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)

select *
from t
order by a
```

That will have the property I want in that all rows with a=1 appear first, then a=2, then a=3.
I could equally specify 'order b a desc' and get the a=3 rows first.

But in fact, I would be just as happy to get all the a=2 rows, then the a=1, then a=3.

So my query above is over-specifying; it is asking the server for a particular sort order when I don't actually want that order; I just want the same values grouped together.  With a large table, the server might be able to query more efficiently if it has more flexibility to choose what order to return the rows, subject to the requirement that the same values are together.

Is there some SQL construct such as

```
   select *
   from t
   order by a indeterminate
```

where I could specify 'any ordering you like, as long as equal elements stay together'?

Comment: The answer to your question is "No".  There are ways to do what you want in SQL, but they are less efficient than just sorting all the data.  `Order by` is the only option that SQL offers.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want isn't an ordering per se, but a clustering.

Comment: Thanks.  Indeed what I want is just to cluster the values.  In the end, I was hoping to cluster by column a, and then within that order by column b.  A simple 'order by a,b' will do it, but might conceivably be slower than needed if there is not an index on a.

Comment: It seems like your needs justify a supporting index.

Comment: Yes, there is an index which allows results to be returned sorted by column a.  Nonetheless there are cases where not having a specified order can be faster.  For example, if the table is partitioned over two disks, in the absence of an 'order by' the DBMS can read from both disks in parallel and return results as soon as they are read.  But a 'cluster by', if it existed, would still allow the DBMS to read from both disks in parallel and send results back to the client without buffering, if rows with a given value for column a are always on either one disk or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything like you describe, a clustered index on the field will usually return rows in order of the indexed value without an order by, but it can't be guaranteed.

However, if you had that index then the cost of the `ORDER BY a` would be trivial.

And of course if you wanted to randomize the order you could do that, but it seemed like you were hoping for a better performing option, and any method to do that would not perform better.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an interesting question. You are looking for clustering, but you don't really care if the clusters are in order. The short answer is that no, there is no such thing.

It is true that ordering the clusters is over-specifying what your requirements are, but for problem sizes that are not ridiculously large, this is the most efficient way to specify the answer. Let's think about how SQL Server would be able to satisfy your request.

Let us assume in the first scenario, your data is in an unordered heap, i.e. no clustered index, and you very very seldom do this request. To satisfy your request, SQL Server can immediately return the first row since you don't care about the order. However, before it can return anything from the second cluster, it must fetch the *entire* result set to know if the last row belongs to the first cluster or not. Thus, you pretty much can't get many results until everything is read from disk.

The first scenario is pretty simple so far, but let us consider how SQL Server might possibly keep track of these clusters. Say you have `n` rows of data belonging to `m` clusters. As SQL Server is traversing through your results, it can return those belonging to the first cluster immediately. However, for the other `m-1` clusters, it needs to store them somewhere.

SQL Server keeps its indices in trees, so let's consider that first. For `m-1` clusters, the tree needs to be `O(log(m))` deep. Hence, the running time to find the cluster that any particular row belongs to is `O(log(m))`. The total running time of this query is `O(n x log(m))`.

Can SQL Server do better? It can by keeping these indices in a hash. The time to find the cluster of a row in a has is `O(1)`. Thus, the total running time is `O(n)`. The trade off here is hashing takes time, a good hash function is hard to determine, and hashes need to reserve more space than they actually require for good performance. Thus, trees are faster and more efficient for small problem sizes.

So in the first scenario, the best we can do is `O(n)`, with a small, but significant constant.

Let us consider the second scenario where you want to do this query more than once in a blue moon. You'll want an index. The index keeps all the rows in clusters, and all the clusters in order for the cost of `O(m)` per insert. What do you get in return? Your query just needs to run through the index from the top (or bottom), returning every row that it sees. This will give you an ordered result. There is no work required in the query. We did all of it on the insert (and update and delete).

All of this assumes that your table is arranged on one disk where the most efficient way to access this data is to run through the data from one end to the other. When you partition your data across disks, this is no longer true. While I think that you should keep your data in memory, you can't always afford that much memory, so there may be a case when partitioning matters.

For the case of partitioning, I would highly recommend a RAID solution so that all your queries would benefit, not just this one. By striping at a smaller scale, you gain performance no matter how your data is distributed. Unless you happen to fetch data that only belongs to one disk, you're okay.

If you are partitioning over asymmetric devices where RAID isn't going to work well, then maybe you can consider stitching together multiple queries, each spanning exactly one partition.